# Javascript break/continue statement

Tags: javascript, break, continue

I can't get this working:

```
var x = 1;

while (x == 1) {
}

function changeX(val) {
     if (val == 1) {
          x = 1;
     } else if (val == 0) {
          x = 0;
          break;
     }
}
```

and no matter what I do, I can't get this working. What I want to do is: I want the loop to stop working when I choose "0" or type it or anything. I have to use break/continue .

No matter what I do, I get wrong use of break or my browser crashes.

PS. In HTML part I put

```
<input type="text" value="1" onchange="changeX(this.value)">
```

Comment: your while loop is not executing any code, you need to invoke `changeX` in your loop, the break isn't needed.  Right now you will just do `while(x==1)` forever which fires nothing

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code will enter an infinite loop even without changeX being called. And changeX doesn't change x... If your code actually worked I would drop javascript as broken.

Comment: While your JavaScript code is running, the page is frozen and no user input is possible.

Comment: `while` is synchronous. It doesn't work together with asynchronous processes, at least not in this way. No other code can run while the `while` loop is executed, therefore `x` cannot be changed, therefore the `while` loop never terminates. Aside that `break` can only be contained in loops. What exactly is your intention with this empty loop?

Comment: @Spark I know changeX doesn't change "x" variable. I want to be able to for example: put 5 and it will raise till number 10 but when I put 0 nothing happens.

Comment: @silk your code doesnt match what you want....

Comment: @FelixKling like I've said I want to put a number.. like (again) 5 and make it raise till number 10 or even 50 or 100, but when I put 0 nothing will happen. So I can't use 'while' loop with break/continue?

Comment: Of course you can use `while` loop with `break/continue`, but that's not what you are doing in your code. You are using `break` *outside* of the `while` loop. And it's not clear why you have a loop at all. The loop is *empty*. It doesn't do anything. You have to explain better what you are trying to do.

Comment: @FelixKling I meant something like Jonas did. Thanks for the help and pointing my errors everyone. I didn't noticed that loop was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Making your code work:**

While will block the browsers thread. Therefore, you cannot click.
Do:

```
var x=false;
function react(){
     if(x){return;}
    //your code
    console.log("sth");//e.g.
    setTimeout(react,0);
}
react();
```

Now you can do your UI stuff

```
function changeX(val) { 
    if (val == 0) { 
        x = true;
    }
}
```

**What you really want:**

```
var timer=false;

function input(val){
    if(timer){
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer=false;
    }
    if(val){
        timer=setInterval(function(){
        val++;
        alert(val);

        if(val==10){
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer=false;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

<input oninput="input(this.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h3>Break Statement</h3>
   <script>
        let num=0;
        while(num<5){
            num++;
            if((num==3)){
                break;
            }else{
                document.write("num is: "+num+"<BR/>")
            }
        }
        document.write("When if condition is true: while Loop Terminated");
    </script>


 <h3>Continue Statement</h3>
    <script>
        let val=0;
        while(val<5){
            val++;
            if(val==3){
                // skip the current loop iteration and jump to the next iteration
                continue;
            }
            document.write("val = "+val+"<BR/>");
        }
    </script>
```